# PersistenceUnitPostProcessor Implementation not working during junit test

Tags: spring, junit, hibernate-mapping, persistence.xml, post-processing

I have implemented a PersistenceUnitPostProcessor for scanning the entities in different packages and not listing them in the persistence.xml.

Sadly, it is only working during deployment but not when running junit tests.

The Processor is declared in the context application xml as follow:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryMdm"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.mypackage.MyPersistenceUnitPostProcessor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The packages are listed as:

```
<util:properties id="entitiesScanProperties">
    <prop key="packagesToScan">package1.entities,package2.entities.view,package3.entities</prop>
</util:properties>
```

The logic:

```
public class MyPersistenceUnitPostProcessor implements PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcePatternResolver resourceLoader;

    @Value("#{entitiesScanProperties['packagesToScan']}")
    private String[] packagesToScan;

    @Override
    public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(final MutablePersistenceUnitInfo mutablePersistenceUnitInfo) {
        try {
            List<Resource> resourcesList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
            for (String packageToScan : packagesToScan) {
                packageToScan = packageToScan.replace(".", "/");
                final Resource[] packageResources = resourceLoader.getResources(String.format("classpath:%s/*.class", packageToScan));
                resourcesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(packageResources));
            }
            final Resource[] resources = new Resource[resourcesList.size()];
            resourcesList.toArray(resources);

            for (Resource resource : resources) {
                final CachingMetadataReaderFactory cachingMetadataReaderFactory = new CachingMetadataReaderFactory();
                final MetadataReader metadataReader = cachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(resource);
                if (metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().isAnnotated(javax.persistence.Entity.class.getName())) {
                    mutablePersistenceUnitInfo.addManagedClassName(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName());
                }
            }
            mutablePersistenceUnitInfo.setExcludeUnlistedClasses(true);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    }
```

The Test definition:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context-test.xml" })
@DatabaseDataAsResource(locations = { "/META-INF/testdata/dbunit/master-dataset.xml", "/META-INF/testdata/dbunit/complaints-dataset.xml" })
public class FuelComplaintServiceImplIntegrationTest extends TestBase {
}
```

The super class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, TestExecutionLifecycleListener.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public abstract class TestBase {

}
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private     com.company.repository.DataProviderRepository com.company.service.impl.ProviderConfigurationServiceImpl.dataProviderRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataProviderRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class package1.entities.DataProviderEntity
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 43 more
```

What can be the issue, that the Processor works during deplyoment but not druing unit testing? Am I overseeing something?

Any hint is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may meet such a Problem.

The reason for the error was this expression:

```
"classpath:%s/*.class"
```

Changing it to:

```
"classpath*:%s/*.class"
```

resolved the error.

The problem was, that the first expression will just look in the first path found. Some classes needed won't be there like in this case the Entities causing the such error messages.

The second expression will tell the ResourcePatternResolver to look in all classes directories matching the path pattern e.g.

```
../classes/package1/Entity.class

../test-classes/package1/ServiceTest.class
```

In my case, it was looking before only to:

```
../test-classes/package1/ServiceTest.class
```

Hope this helps someone.